# How do I split text according to multiple conditions efficiently in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Hey so I am expecting an input from user this way:

```py
1 = 20,
2 = 14,
3-5 = 10
```

Now what I want from this is a dict:

```py
{1:20,
2:14,
3:10,
4:10,
5:10}
```

I want to split the user input by `,` and `=` So I did:

```py
for i in points.replace('\n','').split(','):
  yield i.split("=")
```

I got lists containing 2 elements:

```py
['1 ', ' 20']
['2 ', ' 14']
['3-5 ', ' 10']
```

All this was smooth but where I get struck is the third list (`['3-5 ', ' 10']`), I want that to be converted to a range so I could get the final dict I want and I could figure out some hacky way but I don't think I am following the best approach for what I am trying to achieve here.
Can you suggest me a better and an efficient way to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
result = {}
for line in points.replace('\n', '').split(','):
    line_values = [value.strip() for value in line.split('=')]
    if '-' in line_values[0]:
        range_idx = line_values[0].split('-')
        num_range = [i for i in range(int(range_idx[0]), int(range_idx[1])+1)]
        for key in num_range:
            result[key] = int(line_values[1])
    else:
        result[int(line_values[0])] = int(line_values[1])
```

The dictionary 'result' is populated with integers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work like this. Need to iterate over the key.

```
result = {}
for i in points.replace('\n','').split(','):
  if "-" not in i:
    splitted = i.split("=")
    result[str(splitted[0])] = str(splitted[1])
  else:
      i_split = i.split("=")
      new_range = i_split[0].split("-")
      for j in range(int(new_range[0], int(new_range[1] + 1)):
        result[str(j)] = str(i_split)

print("Here yours: ", result)
```

Note: I make this in string, if you need it in integer, just change the `str()` to `int()`

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this code

```
#===== if you want, you can do this too.
points="1 = 20,\n2 = 14,\n3-5 = 10"
x=[]
for i in points.split(','):
    x.append(i.strip("\n").split("="))
#=====
x=[['1 ', ' 20'],
['2 ', ' 14'],
['3-5 ', ' 10']]
dic1={}
for i in x:
    if "-" in i[0]:
        i2=i[0].split("-")
        for j in range(int(i2[0]), int(i2[1])+1):
            dic1.update({j:i[1]})
    else:
        dic1.update({i[0]:i[1]})
print(dic1)
```